# Font corrupted on Discord after upgrading to 18.04

Tags: fonts, 18.04

The discord's default font (Noto) seems corrupted after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 from 17.10.Instead of running update-manager I did it by changing from artful(?) to bionic and I think that this might be a problem.Can i re-install the font?

Comment: I don't think avoiding update-manager is the problem, since I upgraded in the normal way and I have the same issue as you.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be an issue with libfreetype6 2.8.1. IT has been reported that downgrading to 2.8.0 fixes the issue, but I'd rather avoid messing with core system libraries and just wait for a fix.

Temporary workaround is to open the Chrome inspector in the Discord app with CTRL + SHIFT + I and run in the console `document.getElementById("app-mount").style["transform"] = "scaleX(1.0000001)"`

This has to be done every time Discord is started.

Answer (score 2):

Update to discord-0.0.5 at http://discordapp.com/

They fixed the issue.